404 when making post request in vite/react but gets 200 OK in postman for the same request
for some reason i get 404 when trying to make http requests form my react app while the http requests work fine for the same url in postman. but it only works in postman when i disconnect from my react app. if i npm run dev my react app i get 404 in both postman and my react app. i have added my code below.
App.jsx
import { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const url = "http://localhost:3000/users";
    const user = { name, email };
    try {
      const data = await axios.post(url, user);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error.message);
    }

  };

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <label>
            Name
            <input
              type="text"
              value={name}
              onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
            />
          </label>
          <label>
            Email
            <input
              type="text"
              value={email}
              onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
            />
          </label>
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
        {message && <p>{message}</p>}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;


index.js
import express from "express";
import connectToDB from "./database/db.js";
import userRoutes from "./routes/userRoutes.js";
import cors from "cors";

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
connectToDB();

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Server is running");
});

app.use("/users", userRoutes);

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`);
});


userRoutes.js
import express from "express";
import {
  addUser,
  getUserByEmail,
  deleteUserByEmail,
} from "../controllers/userController.js";

const router = express.Router();

router.post("/", addUser);
router.get("/:email", getUserByEmail);
router.delete("/", deleteUserByEmail);

export default router;


userController.js

import user from "../database/models/user.js";

export const addUser = async (req, res) => {
  console.log("incoming request");
  const { name, email } = req.body;
  try {
    const newUser = new user({ name, email });
    await newUser.save();
    console.log("saved new user");
    res.send(newUser);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("user not saved");
    res.send(error.message);
  }
};

export const getUserByEmail = async (req, res) => {
  const currentEmail = req.params.email;
  console.log(currentEmail);
  try {
    const currentUser = await user.findOne({ email: currentEmail });
    console.log("successfully sent user");
    res.send(currentUser);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("could not retrieve user");
    res.send(error.message);
  }
};

export const deleteUserByEmail = async (req, res) => {
  const currentEmail = req.body.email;
  console.log(req.body);
  try {
    const removedUser = await user.deleteOne({ email: currentEmail });
    console.log(removedUser);
    console.log("successfully removed user");
    res.send(removedUser);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("could not remove user");
    res.send(error.message);
  }
};


not really sure what is causing this, tried changing the ports from 5173 to 3000 but problem remains.

Solved it, client was connecting to the same port as server. Hade them connecting to seperate localhost ports and it worked fine
